# Quartile in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

table1

```
member
10010
10020
10030
10040
10050
10060
10070
10080
10090
10100
```

I want to divide the 10 rows into 4 buckets. I did the following:

```
select a.*, NTILE(4) over(order by member) as segment1 from table1 a
order by member;
```

But this gives me equal distribution in 4 buckets.

I would like to have decreasing 4 buckets. 1st one to have 40% then 30%, then 20%, then 10%.

Output should be:

```
member     segment1
10010      1
10020      1
10030      1
10040      1
10050      2
10060      2
10070      2
10080      3
10090      3
10100      4
```

How can I achieve it using Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` and `count()` for this:

```
select a.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by member) <= 0.4 * count(*) over () then 1
             when row_number() over (order by member) <= 0.7 * count(*) over () then 2
             when row_number() over (order by member) <= 0.9 * count(*) over () then 3
             else 4
        end) as segment
from table1 a
order by member;
```

Of course, you can also use `ntile()`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when ntile(10) over (order by member) <= 4 then 1
             when ntile(10) over (order by member) <= 7 then 2
             when ntile(10) over (order by member) <= 9 then 3
             else 4
        end) as segment
from table1 a
order by member;
```

Answer (score 4):

One simple approach would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY member) / COUNT(*) OVER () rn
    FROM table1 t
)

SELECT
    member,
    CASE WHEN rn <= 0.4 THEN 1
         WHEN rn <= 0.7 THEN 2
         WHEN rn <= 0.9 THEN 3
         ELSE 4 END AS segment1
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    member;
```

[image]

### Demo